# WPF: two connected Datagrids, disable one of them

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have two Datagrids that show below each other

```
Datagrid: "Step"
ID    Info    Info1    Info2    IsDone
1     x                           YES
2     y                           YES
3     z                           NO
--------------------------------------------------
Datagrid: "SubStep"
ID    SubInfo    SubInfo1    SubInfo2    IsDone
1     a                                    YES
1     b                                    NO
1     c                                    NO
1     d                                    NO
--------------------------------------------------
```

These datagrids are binded to two separate datasets which are connected through column ID
Datagrid "Step" is the main one. On selection change it will populate Datagrid "SubStep" with values (1 Step has n SubSteps).

I also have two buttons: "DoStep" and "DoSubStep" - they set the bool value in the column IsDone.

**Now the actual problem:**

I select one row in Datagrid "Step" and click on "DoStep"
I want to disable the "Step" (can't change selected row, don't activate SelectionChanged event) until all rows in "SubStep" have been finished (by clicking DoStep for each row).

Is it possible to disable selection change or is there a workaround to do it?

Comment: Why have a separate grid? Why not use the row details functionality to show the details grid? Here's a visual example using the Telerik grid, but it's a common thing to all grids: http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radgridview/row-details/template

Comment: The easy answer is I took the existing code after someone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to handle selection event before selection happens without workaround.

The easiest way is to disable the datagrid

```
 gridName.IsEnabled = false;
```

or to handle selection event and unselect everything:

```
gridName.UnselectAll();
```